# Accidentally removed IAM roles for my account in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I recently subscribed to GCP , created a trial billing account to explore all GCP services. I had quite experimented with services and when i was playing around with the IAM services , I accidentally deleted my own service role and now I cannot see my project under the dropdown nor access any GCP resources.

I have tried to do

```
gcloud projects undelete my-project-id
```

in the CLI,
but end up getting `gcloud.projects.undelete) User does not have permission to access projects instance [my-project-id:undelete] (or it may not exist): The caller does not have permission`

Please help. I have many findings and also it's a billed account. There is no proper GCP support aswell.

EDIT: I am sure the project exists since i can access my BigQuery tables , look into the data in the tables aswell (but can't access anything else) and also when I try to use `gcloud projects create`  I get an error saying someother org is using the same project name.

Also , kindly do not mark this as duplicate since I've referred to every other solution on stackoverflow before posting my question. Kindly help.

Comment: `gcloud projects undelete my-project-id` is only to undelete projects, not to restore IAM permissions. If you removed your permissions from the project and you were the only one added there you need to contact GCP support.

Comment: Hey @Puteri, I've searched everywhere in GCP console but could not find a space for raising technical support tickets. Could you kindly tell me how to get in contact with GCP support ?

Comment: You need to buy a support package, at least the standard one. See the pricing here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/standard#pricing and how to set up it here https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/purchasing-setting-up-standard

Comment: had multiple findings associated with that project and hence wanted to retrieve it!
It's a shame Google charges for tech support. Nevermind! I guess i'll just go ahead and create another GCP account with another Gmail ID. Atleast now I know what I should and shouldn't be doing. Thank you anyways!